# How to build query with optional parts in MongoDB java driver 3.0

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I would like to create method that composes db query using optional query parts.

In old days I could write method like:

```
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.QueryBuilder;

public DBObject createQuery(Optional<String> aOpt, Optional<Integer> bOpt) {
    QueryBuilder builder = new QueryBuilder();
    aOpt.ifPresent(a -> builder.and("a").is(a));
    bOpt.ifPresent(b -> builder.and("b").lessThan(b));
    return builder.get();
}
```

how to accomplish it with new MongoDB Java driver 3.0

I tried something like

```
import org.bson.Document;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Filters;

public Document createQuery(Optional<String> aOpt, Optional<Integer> bOpt) {
    Document query = new Document();
    aOpt.ifPresent(a -> query.put("a", a));
    bOpt.ifPresent(b -> query.[nonExistingMethod](Filters.lt("b", b)));
    return query;
}
```

But all filters methods returns BSON which could not be converted to `Document` fluently. It seems that Filters could not be used that way... pretty useless.

Do I miss something.
How to do it wisely?

Comment: Side note - I think you meant for the second `aOpt.ifPresnet` to be `bOpt.ifPresent`